# Different results using sign with mean in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I used the following code in two different applications on two different platforms and got different results.
b is a vector of dimensions [w,3,200,200] Where w is the batch-size

```
grad=b.sign()

grad=torch.mean(grad,dim=0)
```

In one case i got what i expected as output from the final grad of + and - 0,222 and 0,333 etc, while in the other case i got a vector of + and - 1's
It turns out that what i expected got me no improvement in accuracy in the final model, while the case with + and - 1's got excellent accuracy.

So i am trying to replicate the case with + and - 1's but i seem to be getting + and - 0.222's and 0.333's instead.
What could cause such a discrepancy in calculation? could it be python or pytorch version? i tried it both on GPU and CPU with no change. i tried changing the code to calculate the torch.mode() instead but there was no increase in accuracy. Please help.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Why `sign` and `mean` differs or..?

Comment: I found the sign of a batch of vectors, then calculated the mean. i got different results on different platforms from this process. I'm trying to replicate one of the results but cant